EF Core inherited overriding property not saved with the value given to property
I have a  VoucherDefinition class and 4 types derive from that, named:

PublicStaticVoucherDefinition
PublicRandomVoucherDefinition
DedicatedStaticVoucherDefinition
DedicatedRandomVoucherDefinition

The base class is declares as:
public class VoucherDefinition
{
  public virtual VoucherCodeType CodeType {get; set;} // enum, with Random and Static members.
  public virtual VoucherType VoucherType {get; set;} // enum, with Dedicated and Public members
  ... // rest of props
}

And each derived type is meant to have a fixed value for VoucherCodeType and VoucherType. As an example PublicStaticVoucherDefinition is declares as:
public class PublicStaticVoucherDefinition: VoucherDefinition
{
  public override VoucherCodeType CodeType { get => VoucherCodeType.Static; set { } }
  public override VoucherType VoucherType { get => VoucherType.Public; set { } }
}

As I try to save a new entity, the VoucherType won't be saved with the correct value. Here is a pseducode showing the issue:
var def = new PublicStaticVoucherDefinition();
// def.VoucherType = VoucherType.Public;  // won't change anything even if uncommented.
AppDb.Set<VoucherDefinition>().Add(def);
await AppDb.SaveChangesAsync(); // Database, has saved VoucherType as Dedicated!! Why?

I expect to see that VoucherType.Public is saved into database, however I see the value of that column is VoucherType.Dedicated!. What's wrong with my setup?
More Context
Just before the AppDb.SaveChangesAsync is called I can see that the VoucherType property has the correct value of VoucherType.Public however the ChangeTracker shows in DebugContext that the added entity has VoucherType.Dedicated value, which is wrong!

This is ultimately a misuse of inheritance. Using sub-classes like this while the mapped entity is the base class doesn't work because EF will only be aware of the property values that were initialized. You would get a bit further ensuring that your setter is `protected' then setting the appropriate value in each subclass constructor. However it's still a bad way to go about it. Just use VoucherDefinition, if you want inheritance then create a single enum for each combination and map the sub-classes using that as a discriminator. This hacky approach will be no end of issues.

@StevePy subclasses are all mapped to database using TPH strategy. Do you mean "misuse" regarding OOP in general, or this is a misuse of EF Core's support of inheritance?. EF has created a discriminator column automatically, and I expect it to do the type casing while retrieving rows, itself. Maybe I didn't fully understand your suggested approach. BTW, I got it working by adding backing fields to virtual properties and initializing backing fields in constructors of derived types.
I'm still looking for clarifications from others if there exists any standard approach.

Is Dedicated the 0 value of the Enum? Perhaps even the default column value? In that case EF probably sees that the property has its default configured value and so doesn't emit it. How are the entities configured?

Using an ORM doesn't change the fact you're still working with tables and columns. Overriding a property to change it from a normal property to a computed one would cause issues even with a plain old C# class, because it would change the contract of the base class.. The base class says that the property can be set. Other developers, never mind EF, can't guess that the contract has changed

@PanagiotisKanavos 1.Yes Dedicated is the 0 value of VoucherType enum. 2. Yes 0 is default of associated column in database. 3. What do you mean by EF probably sees that the property has its default configured value and so doesn't emit it? I've explicitly set value to the property why would EF not see it? 4.I'll update question with entity configurations.

@PanagiotisKanavos Thank you I now see why such overriding is not considered good. Turning such properties into protected solves the issue you pointed out I think.

@PanagiotisKanavos Entity configurations are all the defaults. I've not added any conf to these classes and properties.
